# A Historical Event

Tags: mathematics, rebus

What historical event does the following rebus represent?
$$
\therefore \forall A, B: (A \cap B = \emptyset) \implies (A \neq B)
$$

Hint:

> $\forall x \in S, \text{ where } |S| = 9.$ This isn't a rebus, but it describes one aspect of the event.

Comment: I believe it is $LaTeX$ rebus, not math haha.

Comment: this is false, let $A=B=\emptyset$

Comment: Your hint is not a fully formed mathematical statement.

Comment: @Deusovi I know, unfortunately. Couldn't think of a better way to state it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "An Historical" or am I old and that's not how it is anymore?

Comment: @Leppy: It's "an" if you don't pronounce the H. Some accents pronounce it, some don't.

Comment: you can prove if $A\cup B=A\cap B$, then $A=B$, does this change anything?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No, you're thinking too much about the strict mathematical meaning of this. It's a rebus, not a mathematical proof.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is:

> Brown v. Board of Education

Explanation:

> Brown v. Board of Education refuted the idea of the "separate, but equal" doctrine. The main statement is that if sets A and B are disjoint, then it's implied A is not equal to B. Another way to describe disjoint sets is [separate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separated_sets). So in other words, if A and B are separate, they are NOT equal.

As for the hint (credit goes to [pacoverflow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4450/pacoverflow) for figuring this out):

> Brown v. Board of Education was a unanimous 9-0 decision and there are 9 elements in set S (the set of Supreme Court members with concurring opinions).

Comment: Very close, but it's a more specific event. You don't have the right explanation for the hint.

Comment: Sweet, took another shot at it. :)

Comment: Nope, still don't have it.

Comment: Third time's a charm? :)

Comment: I think this answer is correct, and I also think I know what the hint refers to! Should I post my own answer?

Comment: It was a unanimous 9-0 decision.

Comment: @pacoverflow Bingo. Tonkleton, edit that in (with credit) and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Done and done. Thanks @pacoverflow for the assistance and OP for the riddle!

Answer (score 1):

Hm. Well, a literal translation yields:

> Therefore, all sets that don't intersect are not the same.

I'm not sure how to relate this to a common phrase yet.

Comment: I think it should be all sets that `do intersect`

Comment: No, the intersection is the empty set. This means they don't intersect.